# correct implementation of Hinge loss minimization for gradient descent

Tags: java, machine-learning

I copied the hinge loss function from [here](https://code.google.com/p/java-statistical-analysis-tool/source/browse/trunk/JSAT/src/jsat/lossfunctions/HingeLoss.java?r=762) (also LossC and LossFunc upon which it's based. Then I included it in my gradient descent algorithm like so:

```
  do 
  {
    iteration++;
    error = 0.0;
    cost = 0.0;

    //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
    for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
    {

      // 1. Calculate the hypothesis h = X * theta
      hypothesis = calculateHypothesis( theta, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );

      // 2. Calculate the loss = h - y and maybe the squared cost (loss^2)/2m
      //cost = hypothesis - outputs__train[p];
      cost = HingeLoss.loss(hypothesis, outputs__train[p]);
      System.out.println( "cost " + cost );

      // 3. Calculate the gradient = X' * loss / m
      gradient = calculateGradent( theta, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size, cost, number_of_files__train);

      // 4. Update the parameters theta = theta - alpha * gradient
      for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
      {
          theta[i] = theta[i] - LEARNING_RATE * gradient[i];
      }

    }

    //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
    error += (cost*cost);       

  /* Root Mean Squared Error */
  //System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( error/number_of_files__train ) );
  System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( error/number_of_files__train ) );

  } 
  while( error != 0 );
```

But this doesnt work at all. Is that due to the loss function? Maybe how I added the loss function to my code?

I guess it's also possible that my implementation of gradient descent is faulty.

Here are my methods for calculating the gradient and the hypothesis, are these right?

```
static double calculateHypothesis( double[] theta, double[][] feature_matrix, int file_index, int globo_dict_size )
{
    double hypothesis = 0.0;

     for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
     {
         hypothesis += ( theta[i] * feature_matrix[file_index][i] );
     }
     //bias
     hypothesis += theta[ globo_dict_size ];

     return hypothesis;
}

static double[] calculateGradent( double theta[], double[][] feature_matrix, int file_index, int globo_dict_size, double cost, int number_of_files__train)
{
    double m = number_of_files__train;

    double[] gradient = new double[ globo_dict_size];//one for bias?

    for (int i = 0; i < gradient.length; i++) 
    {
        gradient[i] = (1.0/m) * cost * feature_matrix[ file_index ][ i ] ;
    }

    return gradient;
}
```

The rest of the code is [here](https://github.com/h1395010/gradient_diss-1-ent_1-id) if you're interested to take a look.

Below this sentence is what those loss functions look like. Should I use the `loss` or `deriv`, are these even correct?

```
/**
 * Computes the HingeLoss loss
 *
 * @param pred the predicted value
 * @param y the target value
 * @return the HingeLoss loss
 */
public static double loss(double pred, double y)
{
    return Math.max(0, 1 - y * pred);
}

/**
 * Computes the first derivative of the HingeLoss loss
 *
 * @param pred the predicted value
 * @param y the target value
 * @return the first derivative of the HingeLoss loss
 */
public static double deriv(double pred, double y)
{
    if (pred * y > 1)
        return 0;
    else
        return -y;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the Hinge loss function, so will read about it, but can you tell us a bit about the problem you are trying to solve? What is in data.csv? What function are you trying to approximate with gradient descent (are you using GD for linear regression? logistic regression? some other function?) This can help us understand what is going on here.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a classification problem, as input I have feature vectors, bag of words style, i.e. each training example is a frequency count against the total words over all documents (the global dictionary) of the words that appear in that particular document and how many times, so based on weights learned from this I want to say if a document is about sports or atheism. the class labels are represented as {0, 1}

Comment: And what is the function that you want to use for classifying a document as either sports or atheism? Just to clarify: I am trying to understand what is happening. At the moment your hypothesis seems to be a linear combination of your weights. Is that correct?

Comment: i guess gradient descent would train the weights, and then i apply a record to those weights and that will generate a 0 for one kind of label and a 1 for the other, is that what you mean by linear combination?

Comment: Hm, ok. I think I get it now. It seems like you are trying to design a Linear SVM without actually using support vectors? You can use gradient descent to train a linear SVM for sure, but your approach is a bit strange. First, lets try to fix the obvious: for an SVM (and for the Hinge loss function) your classes have to be -1 and 1, not 0 and 1. If you are encoding your classes as 0 and 1, the Hinge loss function will not work.

Comment: I'm the author of JSAT. Please add a GPL v3 license to your github page as a requirement of using my code under the GPL.

Comment: @Raff.Edward sure, my bad. can you provide a link to whatever I need to add and I'll add it.

Comment: This https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing/ explains how, you just need to add a file indicating that the code is under GPL. I hope JSAT was helpful in some way.

Comment: cool. thank you for that reminder, I'd never thought about that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided for gradient does not look like a gradient of Hinge loss. Take a look at a valid equation, for example here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/gradient-of-hinge-loss

Comment: I was thinking I that the calculation of the gradient and the calculation of the loss function were two seperate pieces, is that not right? I thought the loss fucntion would take the place of `cost` in the gradient calculation, I just made an edit to my original post to show the loss function code which is indeed similar to what you posted there. do you think what I just said is correct?

Comment: derivative/gradient of each loss function is different. You need to implement both Hinge loss [loss in the code you provided] and valid gradient [using deriv from the code you provided].

Comment: @lejlot: I was slowly getting there in the comments.
Mathew: The point of gradient descent is that it optimizes a function by following its gradient. So in order to optimize the Hinge loss function, you need to follow the gradient (derivative) of that function, and not of another function. However, for hinge loss to even work in the first place, you need to encode your classes differently: without that, GD will still not manage to do anything useful.